# json_encode создаёт строку ввиде массива где ошибка

Tags: php, json

Есть масcив. `var_dump()` выводит

```
array(3) { 
   [0]=> string(1) "1" 
   [1]=> string(1) "3" 
   [2]=> string(1) "4" 
}
```

делаю

```
echo $t = json_encode($arr_section);
```

выводит `["1","3","4"]`
Почему не делает json строку?

Comment: Как, в Вашем представлении, должна выглядеть  "json строка"?

Comment: Как то так) '{ "name": "Вася", "age": 35, "isAdmin": false, "friends": [0,1,2,3]

Comment: Так конвертируйте в JSON объект, у которого есть свойства `name`, `age`, `isAdmin` и т.д..

Comment: Вы удивитесь, но json_encode __возвращает строку__.

Comment: А как делается такой json a:5:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:518;i:518;i:61;i:61;} у него ключ стринг '0' , '1' и тд?

Comment: Ну да, вы на вход json_encode подали php-массив с тремя элементами - на выходе получили json-массив с тремя элементами. Всё отработало абсолютно корректно. php не станет выдумывать за вас name, age и прочие friends; какой объект в json_encode запихнёте, такой json и получите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё правильно, json массив. Для того чтоб получился json объект, сделай массив ассоциативным

```
$arr1 = [
    'foo' => 1, 
    'bar' => 'someValue',
];
echo json_encode($arr1); // {"foo":1,"bar":"someValue"}

$arr2 = [1, 'someValue'];
echo json_encode($arr2); // [1,"someValue"]
```